# USB gives an error on startup

Tags: usb, startup, 23.10

When I startup my PC, I get this error on my screen:

```
[25.886013] usb 2-3: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32
```

Is this possible to fix? If so, how?

**EDIT**

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 013 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 012 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4e8e Primax Electronics, Ltd HP USB Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b3f:2247 Generalplus Technology Inc. GENERAL WEBCAM
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:a503 Dell Computer Corp. AC511 Sound Bar
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 062a:5918 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb -v -s 3:3`:

Comment: Please post in question, so it can be formatted. Difficult to read in a comment. if you unplug everything but keyboard & mouse does it work? then plug in one at a time?